# PHP MYSQL insert date syntax

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

When the date need to insert into mysql table, it prompt this error-

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '','2013-09-11','1', NULL)' at line 2

This is my source code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitsub']))
{
     $stuid = $_POST['stuid'];
     $stuname = $_POST['stuname'];
     $stuemail = $_POST['stuemail'];
     $stumajor = $_POST['stumajor'];
     $appdate = date("Y-m-d");
     $appointment = $_POST['date'];
     $subno = $_POST['subject'];
     $appstatus = 1;

     $tri = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT this_tri FROM trimester"));

     $sql = "INSERT INTO application_subject (app_no, tri_id, sub_id, stu_id, stu_name, stu_email, stu_major, app_date, appointment_date, app_status, app_remark) 
             VALUES (NULL,'$tri[this_tri]','$subno','$stuid','$stuname','$stuemail','$stumajor',$appdate','$appointment','$appstatus', NULL)";

     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
     {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
     }

     echo'<script>alert("Your application has been submited") </script>';
     ob_flush();
}
```

On my mysql, the attribute of is set to date already.

Comment: On the one hand, you're missing a quote before `$appdate'`. On the other - you're using mysqli, so why aren't you using a prepared statement?

Comment: You are wide open to sql injection attacks, consider using parameterized queries or at least calling mysqli_real_escape_string on your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a single quote before the $appdate variable in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `'` character before $appdate'

```
'$stumajor',$appdate'
```

this should be

```
'$stumajor','$appdate'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a quote in the following:

```
'$stumajor',$appdate','$appointment'
```

It should be

```
'$stumajor','$appdate','$appointment'
```